# Xamarin project broken on update CardView package

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, package, cardview

My project was working fine untill I updated this package

> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView

I'm a starter with Xamarin, so I hope anyone here can push me in the right direction.

**Didn't work**

- Delete and reinstall
- Downgrading the package

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug in Xamarin. After a release of a new version everything worked fine. More explanation can be find [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90403/the-referenced-component-xamarin-android-support-xx-could-not-be-found-reappears-on-reload?).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're missing the [Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/) package in your project. But by checking your code of style, I guess that you're probably using Xamarin.Forms toolkit to create your android project. And under this condition, this package should be installed. Any way, you can have a check.

Then, if you're sure that the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` is installed, please check your target version of your android project. The `CardView` requires Xamarin.Android 4.20 or later and Android SDK 5.0(API 21) or later. Please check if the Android SDK is correctly installed via the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the only thing I had to do was a clean rebuild